# select2entity-bundle send second parameter with ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, jquery-select2

i'm using [tetranz/select2entity-bundle](https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle) and I want to send another parameter via ajax to use it inside a query.

```
$builder->add('client', Select2EntityType::class, array(
                'multiple' => false,
                'remote_route' => 'clientquery',
                'class' => 'ProjetsBundle\Entity\Client',
                'primary_key' => 'id',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez un client',
                'language' => 'fr',
                'page_limit' => 50,
            ))
```

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and can be dome using 'remote_params' option

```
 $builder->add('client', Select2EntityType::class, array(
                'multiple' => false,
                'remote_route' => 'clientquery',
                'class' => 'ProjetsBundle\Entity\Client',
                'primary_key' => 'id',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez un client',
                'language' => 'fr',
                'page_limit' => 50,
                'remote_params' => array('secondparameter'=>'value',
                                 'thirdparameter'=>'value')

            ))
```